# Is it possible to add council support and initial members during a runtime upgrade?

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime-upgrade, governance, council

I have a running node without a council configured in genesis. I would like to add a council and initial council members using a runtime upgrade. Is this possible and how would i do it

Comment: What about calling `fn set_members`?

Comment: fn set_memebrs will result in a bad origin error since there are no members completely

Comment: What did you set as your [`SetMembersOrigin`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b23e52d340f1d8c6405c631e5e836f45966df326/frame/collective/src/lib.rs#L219)?

Comment: Am using polkadot-v0.9.37 and the type SetMembersOrigin is not a member of the trait. But i am updating my code to polkadot-v0.9.40 and i will be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by a [storage migration](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/storage-migrations/) (read the linked docs page for details).